# Are TF-IDF and BoW techniques incompatible?

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have studied the [difference between TF-IDF and BoW](http://datameetsmedia.com/bag-of-words-tf-idf-explained/) methods but I have a big doubt about it. I thought that the two methods could be combined, I will explain better. I have a csv file (`MY_DATA`) with thousands of comments from a social network, I would like to use this dataset to create my `BoW` for the creation of a `classification model` of the sentiment of comments (the sentiment of comments is the other variable of `MY_DATA` and is of three types: positive, negative and neutral)

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer()
text_tf = tf.fit_transform(MY_DATA['comments'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text_tf, MY_DATA['sentiment'], test_size=0.2)

#Classification model Multinomial Naive Bayes
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Now that you have seen my script I would like to know if I am using the TF-IDF method correctly. How could I apply the BoW method in my case? Do the two methods inevitably remain incompatible?

Comment: From the article you yourself linked: "Term frequency (tf) is basically the output of the BoW model" so tf-idf starts with BOW, then adds IDF to it to make it more informative. In other words, you don't need to add BOW to your tfidf, because it's already contained within

Comment: thank you very much it was just to be sure

Comment: This isn't really a *programming* question, so it's probably more suitable for [statistics.se], but BoW and TF-IDF are not incompatible at all. Indeed, TF-IDF is just the canonical weighting scheme given to a naive BoW model. Perhaps you can make an academic distinction, but for all intents and purposes, TF-IDF is a type of BoW model. To be precise, it is a well-known weighting scheme for BoW, where, for information retrieval purposes, naive counts are not ideal.